Why do GCC, ICX and Clang not auto-vectorize using AVX-512 based instructions on Intel processors but do the same on AMD?
My code is extremely simple
void x(float* array, float const LOW_THRESHOLD, float const HIGH_THRESHOLD) noexcept
{
    for ( int index = 0; index < 16; ++index )
    {
        array[ index ] = LOW_THRESHOLD < array[ index ] && array[ index ] < HIGH_THRESHOLD ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }
}

The code looks like a poster-child for AVX-512 based vectorization.
I decided to use Godbolt to check
It seems that Clang, ICX and GCC only vectorize for AMD based architectures (Both znver4 and znver5 but not znver3 which does not support AVX512)
However, for Intel I decided to check for:-

Skylake AVX512
Granite Rapids
Emerald Rapids

For all 3, I tried to use the latest of compilers present on Godbolt.
Clang Intel Emerald Rapids (-O3 -march=emeraldrapids)
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   0x3f800000
x(float*, float, float):
        vbroadcastss    ymm0, xmm0
        vmovups ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdi]
        vmovups ymm3, ymmword ptr [rdi + 32]
        vcmpltps        k1, ymm0, ymm2
        vbroadcastss    ymm1, xmm1
        vcmpltps        k1 {k1}, ymm2, ymm1
        vbroadcastss    ymm2, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        vmovaps ymm4 {k1} {z}, ymm2
        vmovups ymmword ptr [rdi], ymm4
        vcmpltps        k1, ymm0, ymm3
        vcmpltps        k1 {k1}, ymm3, ymm1
        vmovaps ymm0 {k1} {z}, ymm2
        vmovups ymmword ptr [rdi + 32], ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret

Clang AMD Ryzen v5 (-O3 -march=znver5)
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   0x3f800000
x(float*, float, float):
        vmovups zmm2, zmmword ptr [rdi]
        vbroadcastss    zmm0, xmm0
        vbroadcastss    zmm1, xmm1
        vcmpltps        k1, zmm0, zmm2
        vcmpltps        k1 {k1}, zmm2, zmm1
        vbroadcastss    zmm0 {k1} {z}, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        vmovups zmmword ptr [rdi], zmm0
        vzeroupper
        ret

My initial opinion was that the optimization was missed.
But that should not be the case as ICX is Intel's own compiler.
Intel and AMD employees both contribute to other open source compilers including Clang and GCC.
The chances of it being missed are a bit low.
Is using AVX512 not recommended on Intel's architecture?
Would that be why both compilers do not auto-vectorize?
(The code is from AVX-512 floating point comparison and masking. Thanks @Terrordrone)
Using -mprefer-vector-width=51 as suggested by @Homer512 seems to work

Performance of AVX512 can be pretty poor , the broadcasts required for your parameters are probably a factor too

@AlanBirtles that does make sense. I have heard of the same in the Ice Lake days. However, does it still apply for Emerald Rapids and what else seems to be confusing is, is AMD's implementation better?

Well, it' still AVX512 instructions, as can be seen by the use of mask registers. It's just not 512 bit vectors. You can successfully force the compilers to generate code with 512 bit vectors by adding -mprefer-vector-width=512 to the optimization options. It would be interesting to see if the compiler judges wrongly in a benchmark.

@Homer512 agreed. I find the lack of 512 bit vectors to be weird. Maybe as you say there are performance ramifications here on Intel platforms?

For Skylake there was a substantial reduction in maximum clock speed. For Emerald there is supposed to be only a minimal slowdown. If I had to guess, one issue with automatic vectorization is that it can appear in places where there is no benefit to it. If it then reduces the clock speed, it will impact the performance negatively. So maybe the compiler makers remain conservative and think programmers who know that it helps will enable the appropriate flags themselves. Again, pure speculation.

@Homer512: Having 512-bit uops in flight also shuts down the vector ALU on port 1, so even without a clock-speed penalty there's a potential local penalty.  But even increasing the loop count from 16 to 16000 doesn't get compilers to use ZMM for emarldrapids, so that isn't why they're avoiding.  re: the frequency/voltage effect: SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency - on recent CPUs, even if "heavy" 512-bit uops don't reduce the frequency, they might still halt the clock for like 50 microseconds to stabilize a higher voltage.

Zen 4 only had 256-bit vector ALUs, with 512-bit uops taking 2 cycles in execution units but reducing front-end pressure and taking less space in the ROB (Reorder buffer) so out-of-order exec can see farther around the same amount of work.  Zen 5 has 512-bit ALUs; IDK if there are frequency/voltage effects due to higher power, but AMD doesn't have fixed frequency caps for different workloads.

Well, I don't think anyone except the designers is going to know the answer to "why" here, we can only guess. Perhaps it wasn't implemented for everything because of low priority, AVX512 is pretty unpopular after all and people who really want AVX512 are people who can vectorize their own loops for own hardware. Basically as you thought that it was missed, just intentionally.
